# Row being duplicated 5 times in listview with custom Adapter

Tags: android, multidimensional-array, arraylist, android-listview

I've an app where i am displaying a record I've got from a webservice. The record has 5 fields, startTime, duration, status, and clientname. (clientname is actually made up of 2 fields first and last). I can get the fields from an arrayList into a String array and then pass that array to the adapter. The fields are displayed in the ListView. All good so far, apart from the same record is shown 5 time in the ListView. Why is this? I pass the array in once to the adapter.

```
public class GetRota extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = GetRota.class.getSimpleName();
    ListView listView;
    Intent intent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.getrotalayout);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.rotalist);
        intent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("rotaArrayBundle");

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList array =  (ArrayList) bundle.get("rotaArray");





        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){

             Log.e(TAG, "array pos " + i + " = " +  array.get(i));

        }

        String record = array.get(0).toString();
        String[] itemsInRecord = record.split(",");
        String[] recordItem = new String[5];

       for(int x = 0; x < itemsInRecord.length; x++){

           Log.e(TAG, "token = " + itemsInRecord[x]);
           recordItem[x] = itemsInRecord[x];
      }

       MySimpleArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, recordItem);
       listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    }// end of onCreate


    private class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
          private final Context context;
          private final String[] values;

          public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.rotarowlayout, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
          }

          @Override
          public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rotarowlayout, parent, false);
           TextView startTime = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstarttime);
           TextView duration = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowduration);
           TextView status = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstatus);
           TextView name = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowclientname);

           startTime.setText("Start Time: " + values[0]);
           duration.setText("Duration:" + values[1]);
           status.setText("Status:" + values[2]);
           name.setText("Client:" + values[3] + values[4]);



            return rowView;
          }
        } 

}// end of GetRota
```

.
[update]

```
private class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
          private final Context context;
          private final ArrayList array;

          public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList array) {
            this.context = context;
            this.array = array;
          }

        public int getCount() {
            return array.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return array.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

          @Override
          public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String[] values = array.get(position).toString();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView;

            if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                    // attributes
                rowView = new View(context);
                // get layout from gridview_item.xml
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rotarowlayout, parent, false);
            } else {
                rowView = (View) convertView;
            }


           TextView startTime = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstarttime);
           TextView duration = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowduration);
           TextView status = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstatus);
           TextView name = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowclientname);

           startTime.setText("Start Time: " + values[position][0]);
           duration.setText("Duration:" + values[position][1]);
           status.setText("Status:" + values[position][2]);
           name.setText("Client:" + values[position][3] + values[position][4]);




            return rowView;
          }
        }
```

[update hitesh]

```
private class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<String[]> list;

        public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String[]> list) 
        {      

        super(context, R.layout.rotarowlayout);
         Log.e(TAG, "inside adapter constructor");
                this.context = context;           
                this.list= list;
              }

              @Override
              public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                  Log.e(TAG, "inside getView");
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

               View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rotarowlayout, parent, false);

               TextView startTime = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstarttime);
               TextView duration = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowduration);
               TextView status = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstatus);
               TextView name = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowclientname);

               String[] values = list.get(position);

               startTime.setText("Start Time: " + values[0]);
               Log.e(TAG, "starttime = " + startTime);
               duration.setText("Duration:" + values[1]);
               status.setText("Status:" + values[2]);
               name.setText("Client:" + values[3] + values[4]);



                return rowView;

              }


              @Override
              public int getCount() {
                  return this.list.size();
              }

    }// end of adapter class
```

Comment: why are you used static array,Create One `Bean class`,that handle easily...[SEE HERE](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html)

Comment: @SamirMangroliya wow looks a little involving, i'll have a look at it thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

actualy ur code is smwt wrong. use 
ArrayList list of string arrays

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
String record = array.get(i).toString();
String[] itemsInRecord = record.split(",");
list.add(record);      }
```

Customize ur adapter also.         MySimpleArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, list);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

```
private class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final Arraylist< String[]> list;
public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context,Arraylist< String[]> list) 
{         
super(context, R.layout.rotarowlayout,list);
        this.context = context;           this.list= list;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rotarowlayout, parent, false);
       TextView startTime = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstarttime);
       TextView duration = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowduration);
       TextView status = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowstatus);
       TextView name = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowclientname);
String[] values= list.get(position);
       startTime.setText("Start Time: " + values[0]);
       duration.setText("Duration:" + values[1]);
       status.setText("Status:" + values[2]);
       name.setText("Client:" + values[3] + values[4]);



        return rowView;}}
```

In ur activity class, replace

```
ArrayList array =  (ArrayList) bundle.get("rotaArray");
    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){

         Log.e(TAG, "array pos " + i + " = " +  array.get(i));

    }
    String record = array.get(0).toString();
    String[] itemsInRecord = record.split(",");
    String[] recordItem = new String[5];

   for(int x = 0; x < itemsInRecord.length; x++){

       Log.e(TAG, "token = " + itemsInRecord[x]);
       recordItem[x] = itemsInRecord[x];
  }

   MySimpleArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, recordItem);
   listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

with

```
 ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();

 ArrayList array =  (ArrayList) bundle.get("rotaArray");

    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){

        String record = array.get(i).toString();
 String[] itemsInRecord = record.split(",");
    list.add(itemsInRecord);  

    }

 MySimpleArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, list);  
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: please give reason for down voting

Comment: hey i haven't voted you down mate, i'm going to have a look at your code now

Comment: hey try this with some small changes, if reqd, as m using phone to answer n pls revert back it works or not

Comment: hi mate, i've updated the original post to reflect your code. It compiles ok, i had to add the getCount() method so that the getView method ran. I'm getting the following exception. 09-21 12:36:18.540: E/AndroidRuntime(27864): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]. it's on the line String[] values = list.get(position);
Do you know how i can get past this exception? thanks alot.

Comment: Class cast exception is due to the fact that ur adding string to array list in activity and trying to retrieve string array. So please check again. I have updated that part for you again

Answer (score 1):

You are converting each record into an array of Strings using split().

```
String[] itemsInRecord = record.split(",");
```

If this is one record, then an array of records should be two dimensional. But your array of records is one dimension.

```
String[] recordItem = new String[5];
```

This gets passed to your adapter, which presumably is creating a row for each index in `values`. For each position, your `getView()` method is reading the same five values each time.

```
startTime.setText("Start Time: " + values[0]);
duration.setText("Duration:" + values[1]);
status.setText("Status:" + values[2]);
name.setText("Client:" + values[3] + values[4]);
```

So you need two dimensions for your data: the number of list items, and the fields for each item. Your current code is using the same dimension as both, and that's why you see five copies of the same record.

```
String[][] recordItem = new String[numRecords][5];
/* ... */
startTime.setText("Start Time: " + values[position][0]);
duration.setText("Duration:" + values[position][1]);
status.setText("Status:" + values[position][2]);
name.setText("Client:" + values[position][3] + values[position][4]);
```

Since you already have it, I suggest using the original `ArrayList` of records and pass that to your adapter. If your records are coming in as some class you've defined, use that! `ArrayList` supports generic types, and you can make your adapter expect that. You don't have to extend `ArrayAdapter`; you can extend `BaseAdapter` and provide the necessary implementations for `getCount()`, `getItem(position)`, `getItemId(position)`, etc., which are all very simple with an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've had a look around at other threads and updated the origianal post. Is this along the lines you meant yesterday? I've extended BaseAdapter, implemented it's methods but there's an error where it reads String[] values = array.get(position).toString(); It's saying cannot convert string to String[]. Could you please advice me on this?